# Error "no existe en el contexto actual" en c#

Tags: c#

Tengo el siguiente código y tengo un error en la linea donde deseo acumular total_interes el valor del capital generado.
Tengo el error del titulo y aunque inicialice la variable en 0, aun dice que "no existe en el contexto actual"
Que esta mal?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            decimal capital, interes, saldo, total_interes, tasa_mensual;
            
            const decimal tasa_anual = 0.36M;
            byte meses;

            Console.WriteLine("Ingresar un capital inicial: ");
            capital = Convert.ToDecimal(Console.ReadLine());

            Console.WriteLine("Ingresar una cantidad de meses: ");
            meses = Convert.ToByte(Console.ReadLine());

            Console.WriteLine("MES | CAPITAL | INTERES | SALDO");

            tasa_mensual = tasa_anual / 12;

            for(int x = 1; x <= meses; x++)
            {
                interes = capital * tasa_mensual;
                saldo = capital + tasa_anual;
                Console.WriteLine(x + "      " + capital + "     " + interes + "    " + saldo);
                //linea del error
                totalinteres += interes;
                capital = saldo;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

Te hizo falta el guion bajo e inicializar la variabl, ese error que te salio se debe a que el compilador no encuentra la variable, clase etc.. con ese mismo nombre. escribiste totalinteres en vez de total_interes que fue el nombre con en que lo declaraste al principio

```
   static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        decimal capital, interes, saldo, total_interes=0, tasa_mensual;

        const decimal tasa_anual = 0.36M;
        byte meses;

        Console.WriteLine("Ingresar un capital inicial: ");
        capital = Convert.ToDecimal(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.WriteLine("Ingresar una cantidad de meses: ");
        meses = Convert.ToByte(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.WriteLine("MES | CAPITAL | INTERES | SALDO");

        tasa_mensual = tasa_anual / 12;

        for (int x = 1; x <= meses; x++)
        {
            interes = capital * tasa_mensual;
            saldo = capital + tasa_anual;
            Console.WriteLine(x + "      " + capital + "     " + interes + "    " + saldo);
            //Error arreglado
            total_interes += interes;
            capital = saldo;
        }
    }
```